# Is it possible to have a variable as a for loop expression?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to merge the xkcd webcomic tiles for comic 1110. So far, I have written about 100 lines, and instead of doing each quadrant of the image separately, I've decided to use functions to do this, repeating for every quadrant and using variables for each quadrant to make the function act differently each time. I would like to be able to something like this, except do it with a different value for a each time.

```
a='((n=$north; n>=1; n--))';
for ${a};
    do "echo Hello World!"
done
```

My problem is, I'm having trouble using variables for the for loop expressions, it goes "line 8: eval "$a"': not a valid identifier", and if I try putting it in parentheses, it goes "line 30: syntax error: arithmetic expression required", and then "line 30: syntax error: `((${a}))". This is what I have so far. Before anyone answers, Yes, I know it has bugs.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Date Created: September 20th, 2012
# Created by Jonathan Bondhus - https://github.com/jbondhus
# Credit to Andreas Reichinger for analysis of image tile placement, xkcd.com for comic. Used ImageMagick code from Antonio Frascarelli.
#
#  This script will merge the files from xkcd comic number 1110, "Click and Drag".

function function_join() {
    echo "#";
    if [[ quadrant -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "# First Quadrant:"; # Join together the first quadrant
    function_quadrant
    else
        if [[ quadrant -eq 2 ]]; then
        echo "# Second Quadrant:"; # Join together the second quadrant
        function_quadrant
        else
            if [[ quadrant -eq 3 ]]; then
            echo "# Third Quadrant:"; # Join together the third quadrant
            function_quadrant
            else
                if [[ quadrant -eq 4 ]]; then
                echo "# Fourth Quadrant:"; # Join together the fourth quadrant
                function_quadrant
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
    echo "#";
    for ${a};
    do
        echo "# row number "$n" ...";
        convert $b;
        for `eval "$c"`;
        do
            if [ $d ];      # If the tile file doesn't exist, an empty square will be used.
                then convert $e;
                else convert $f;
            fi;
        done;
        convert $g;    # Append the image onto the current quadrant
        rm -f $h;
        echo "# ... OK";
        echo "#";
    done;
}

function function_quadrant() {
    if [[ quadrant -eq 1 ]]; then # Set the variables for function_join
    quadrantName="first"
    a='((n=$north; n>=1)); n--'
    b='-size 0x1 xc:white resultn$n''w.png'
    c='((w=$west; w>=1; w--))'
    d='-e $n''n$w''w.png'
    e='+append resultn$n''w.png $n''n$w''w.png resultn$n''w.png'
    f='+append resultn$n''w.png _blank.png resultn$n''w.png'
    g='-append ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png resultn$n''w.png ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png'
    h='resultn$n''w.png'
    else
        if [[ quadrant -eq 2 ]]; then
        quadrantName="second"
        a='n=$north; n>=1; n--'
        b='-size 0x1 xc:white resultn$n''e.png'
        c='e=$east; e<=20; e++'
        d='-e $n''n$e''e.png'
        e='+append resultn$n''e.png $n''n$e''e.png resultn$n''e.png'
        f='+append resultn$n''e.png _blank.png resultn$n''e.png'
        g='-append ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png resultn$n''e.png ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png'
        h='resultn$n''e.png'
        else
            if [[ quadrant -eq 3 ]]; then
            quadrantName="third"
            a='s=1; s<=$south; s++'
            b='-size 0x1 xc:black results$s''w.png'
            c='w=$west; w>=1; w--'
            d='-e $s''s$w''w.png'
            e='+append results$s''w.png $s''s$w''w.png results$s''w.png'
            f='+append results$s''w.png _black.png results$s''w.png'
            g='-append ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png results$s''w.png ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png'
            h='results$s''w.png'
            else
                if [[ quadrant -eq 4 ]]; then
                quadrantName="fourth"
                a='s=1; s<=$south; s++'
                b='-size 0x1 xc:black results$s''e.png'
                c='e=1; e<=20; e++'
                d='-e $s''s$e''e.png'
                e='+append results$s''e.png $s''s$e''e.png results$s''e.png'
                f='+append results$s''e.png _black.png results$s''e.png'
                g='-append ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png results$s''e.png ${quadrantName}Quadrant.png'
                h='results$s''e1.png'
                else # If more than 4 quadrants, just to be safe, exit
                    exit 1
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

for (( quadrant = 0; quadrant < 4; quadrant++ )); do
    function_join
done

echo "#################################"
echo "Joining completed!"
echo "#################################"

exit 0
```

Comment: not sure why you don't use `elif` or better yet, `case ${quad} in first ) do stuff ;; second ) do ... ;; ... esac`. I don't think you need all that indenting, just makes it hard to follow along with what you're doing. that said, interesting problem, consider a rewrite in awk with an occasional call like `cmd="convert " opt1 opt2 opt3 ..; system(cmd) ; ... `. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
./north.sh 
Hello World!  4 5
Hello World!  3 4
Hello World!  2 3
Hello World!  1 2
Hello World!  0 1
```

cat north.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
north=5;
for ((n=$north; n>=1; --n))
do
        ((north--))
     echo "Hello World!  $north $n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not. Syntax parsing occurs prior to parameter expansion (parameters need to be first recognized as such, after all). I would recommend restructuring your code to pass around data, not executable code.

Comment: So what specifically are you thinking? Write it out non-looping? Or nested if statements?